# Python Regex Help Needed (Basic)

Tags: python, regex

I need a python regex which can help me eliminate illegal characters inside a word.

The conditions are as such:

1. The first character must be a-z only
2. All characters in the word should only be a-z (lower case) plus apostrophe ' and hyphen -
3. The last character must be a-z or apostrophe ' only
4. You can assume that the word is always lower-case

Test data:

```
 s = "there is' -potato 'all' around- 'the 'farm-"
```

Expected output:

```
>>>print(s)
there is' potato all' around the farm
```

My code is currently as such but it doesn't work correctly:

```
newLine = re.findall(r'[a-z][-\'a-z]*[\'a-z]?', s)
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried e.g. http://regex101.com/#python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> b=re.findall(r'[a-z][-\'a-z]*[\'a-z]',a)
>>> for i in b: print i
... 
potato
potato
human'
potatoes
```

Comment: I tried using your regex code but it doesn't produce the expected output you have written

Comment: I have tested it on the test data you provided. It worked fine. Still, try this non-greedy version  `b=re.findall(r'[a-z][-\'a-z]*[\'a-z]?',a)`

Comment: Switch to double quotes to eliminate the escaping: `b=re.findall(r"[a-z][-'a-z]*['a-z]?",a)`

Answer (score 1):

Just match only the chars you don't want and remove ith through `re.sub`

```
>>> import re
>>> s = """potato
-potato
'human'
potatoes-"""
>>> m = re.sub(r"(?m)^['-]|-$", r'', s)
>>> print(m)
potato
potato
human'
potatoes
```

**OR**

```
>>> m = re.sub(r"(?m)^(['-])?([a-z'-]*?)-?$", r'\2', s)
>>> print(m)
potato
potato
human'
potatoes
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/zK8jF5/3)

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
[a-z][a-z'\-]*[a-z]|[a-z]
```

Comment: thanks! it's almost accurate but I realize a case that was not caught when I ran a sample code. The beginning of the word contained apostrophe '

Answer (score 0):

Well assuming every word is separated by a space you could find all the valid words with something like [this regex](http://regex101.com/r/mU2xR1/1):

```
(?<= |^)[a-z](?:(?:[\-\'a-z]+)?[\'a-z])?(?= |$)
```

But if you want to eliminate illegal characters I guess you're better of finding the illegal characters and removing them.
Now we assume again that you got a string which should only contain words which are seperated by spaces and nothing else in it.

So first of all we can sub all invalid characters out of the string: `[^a-z-' ]`

After doing this the only thing that could still be invalid would be a `'` or `-` in the beginning of the word or a `-` in the end of the word.

So we sub those out with [this regex](http://regex101.com/r/mX5lG2/1): `(?<= |^)['-]+|-+(?= |$)`